# How to send data from UDP Server to UDP client behind NAT?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I want to send data from UDP server to UDP client. server has public IP and it is listening on know port number so client can send data to server using UDP but client is behind NAT and client is not listening on know port. Server is unable to send data to client when it wish.
 is it possible that client can contact server and server can use that port and public address of client gateway to replay back ?

is there anyway or good way to send data from UDP server to UDP client behind NAT ?

Comment: google hole punching. Involves sending a packet from client to server so the nat thinks a connection is established

Comment: NAT traversal is a well-researched field. Just some starters: 1) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching, 2) http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/09/16/types-of-nat/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Server sending data immediately after receiving an incoming message from UDP client is possible in most cases. Server can send packets to the source ip and port number. But if the server wants to send data whenever it requires, it might not work. NAT would have flushed out the ip/port mapping.

There is one solution I can think of. Not a very efficient way. UDP client should keep on pinging server. This way it prevents NAT from flushing out the mapping by keeping the communication alive.

http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/

The link given above explains UDP Hole Punching.